# Using Hibernate-Search with ONE central index

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, indexing, hibernate-search

I wonder, if it is possible to configure hsearch so that there would bei one central index located on a server?

Because we are many developers in our team it would be much better to work with the same data...

But when i try to configure hsearch with "indexBase=http//my-path-to-index-folder", it doesn't work because it changes to "path/to/vm-directory/http//my-path-to-index-folder"
Could someone tell me how to configure hib-Search so that every teammember could work with the same index?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Indexes in Hibernate Search are not identified using an URL. The *indexBase* attribute is meant to point to a specific filesystem path.
A filesystem could reside on a network share, so you could do that to share an index across a team.

Generally speaking though a team of developers would normally have independent indexes in their local machine - and an independent database - so that they can run tests without interfering with each other's experiments.

For a production deployment, an index is generally shared across multiple servers using the [Infinispan storage](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#infinispan-directories) or a [master/slave approach using JMS queues](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#_back_end).